# iOS - Draw text in table like structure in PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, core-text

I am trying to create a pdf like below image . I created string with  `NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@    %@     %@   %@ \n",monthsInfo.month,monthsInfo.principal,monthsInfo.interest,monthsInfo.balance];`
I just loop this code for each row and constructed a string.

[image]

I got pdf with the code

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

                // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
                currentPage++;
                [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

                // Render the current page and update the current range to
                // point to the beginning of the next page.
                currentRange = [self renderPage:1 withTextRange:currentRange andFramesetter:framesetter];
```

I got the pdf like below image and I found formatting issue, Can any one help me to structure this pdf , or please give your suggestion which approach I need to take to construct it properly.

[image]

Comment: Size of every char is different. I would try with tab and not with space in stringWithFormat. (Maybe another font could work):

Comment: @Watsche, I tried with tab , even with tab i find mis-alignment.

Comment: than you have to take a monospaced font

Comment: @Watsche, as the value in the columns may have different number of digits , do you think monospaced font will work in that case.

Comment: That is a different problem. You have to check for the number of digits and to insert space to your string for example. I was now focused on the format issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with below code , and I find x,y position using logic and set the frames and just draw it.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                @[font, textColor,backgroundColor]
                                                           forKeys:
                                @[NSFontAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName]];
[text drawInRect:frame withAttributes:attributes];
```

I followed tutorial here [Generating PDF Documents](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-pdf-documents--mobile-11265)

Now I got expected output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In some fonts you have a different char width. That way you will never get a straight column. One way is to use a monospaced fonts with the same char width. 
Maybe the Tab "\t" will also work. Anyway it is better, than the space.